# How to use listings inside pgfplots captions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, listings, verbatim

I need to add a (general) listings code in a plot caption. For some reason `listings` (inline) doesn't interact well with `\addlegendentry`, what can I do to make the same code work outside and inside an `\addlegendentry` environment?

Note that it even gives an strange result (see image), where the phrase is in the wrong order.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinline[]|(double x){bbbb}| %ok

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addlegendentry{\lstinline[]|(double x){bbbb;}|}; %not ok, garbage
\addplot+[mark=none, line join=round, fill opacity = 0.5, ] coordinates {
( 1, 2 )
( 3, 4)
}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: weird listing inside pgfplot]

One workaround I found is to put `\{`...`\}` in the `\legendentry` case, but doing so doesn't do the same thing outside the `pgfplot` and I want to use the *same* code regardless if possible. Maybe the solution is an option that I have to pass to the `tikzpicture` environment, or to the `tikz` package or to the `listing`.

(These `verb`-like environments always give me headaches.)

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to Gonzalo's clarification, I made this code that allows to use the same code inside and outside the caption, it uses a hack (`\textrm`, other solutions are welcomed):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{listings}
\begin{document}
\textrm{\lstinline[]|(double x)\{bbbb\}|} %ok
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[small]
\addlegendentry{\textrm{\lstinline[]|(double x)\{bbbb\}|}}; %now ok
\addplot+[mark=none, line join=round, fill opacity = 0.5, ] coordinates {( 1, 2 )}; 
\addlegendentry{\lstinline[]|(double x){bbbb;}|}; % not ok, garbage
\addplot+[mark=none, line join=round, fill opacity = 0.5, ] coordinates {( 1, 2 )}; 
\addlegendentry{\lstinline[]|(double x)\{bbbb\}|}; % not what one expects
\addplot+[mark=none, line join=round, fill opacity = 0.5, ] coordinates {( 1, 2 )}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `\texttt{...}` in this case?

Comment: It is not in the simple example, but I want to use the fancy formatting that listings provides, besides the possibility to use other special characters like curly braces and underscores.

Comment: all that is possible with `\texttt{...}` for not so long examples which are not longer than one line.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `\lstinline` inside arguments is experimental; see this subsection in the documentation:

> **5.1 Listings inside arguments**
>
> There are some things to consider if you want to use `\lstinline` or
>   the listing environment inside arguments. Since TeX reads the argument
>   before the "lst- macro" is executed, this package can’t do anything to
>   preserve the input: spaces shrink to one space, the tabulator and the
>   end of line are converted to spaces, TeX's comment character is not
>   printable, and so on. Hence, you must work a bit more. You have to put
>   a backslash in front of each of the following four characters: `\{}%`.
>   Moreover you must protect spaces in the same manner if: (i) there are
>   two or more spaces following each other or (ii) the space is the first
>   character in the line. That’s not enough: Each line must be terminated
>   with a "line feed" `^^J`. And you can’t escape to LaTeX inside such
>   listings!

I am afraid the only solution is then, as suggested in the documentation, to use `\{` and `\}`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addlegendentry{\lstinline[]|(double x)\{bbbb;\}|}; 
\addplot+[mark=none, line join=round, fill opacity = 0.5, ] coordinates {
( 1, 2 )
( 3, 4)
}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative would be to use the `listings` interface to `fancyvrb` (or to use `fancyvrb` directly):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\fvset{commandchars=\\\{\}}

\begin{document}
\Verb!(double x)\{bbbb;\}!

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addlegendentry{\Verb!(double x)\{bbbb;\}!}; 
\addplot+[mark=none, line join=round, fill opacity = 0.5, ] coordinates {
( 1, 2 )
( 3, 4)
}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, that clarifies the current state of things. What is most annoying is that the code inside an argument must be different than outside the argument. I can afford the extra complication of the `\{ \}`. Which brings another question, is there a *dummy* environment that I can used outside pgfplots? in such a way that the same code will work inside pgfplots and inside the argument. (for example I tried `\par{(double x)\{\}}` but it didn't work.

Comment: ok, `\textrm` seems to put both `listings` in equal footing (see my question, for proposed code.) If you have a better solution please let me know.

Comment: @alfC I don't seem to see, in your example, any difference with or without `\textrm`; am I missing something? In the meantime, I provided an alternative in my updated answer.

Comment: The idea is that this code `\textrm{\lstinline[]|(double x)\{bbbb\}|}` can be used in `legendentry` *or* outside without modification, giving the same effect. Your solution using `fancyverb` is an improvement but note that the curly brackets are omitted in the resulting document.

Comment: @alfC my bad. I forgot to add the `commandchars` option for `fancyvrb`. I updated my answer. Using `fancyvrb` and `commandchars` as defined in the example, you can use the same string both inside `\addlegendentry` and in regular text.

Comment: hey, but you just removed the most important part of the solution... which is to use `listings`' `lstinline`. I need to use `listings` for the syntax formatting. This the current code (still doesn't work): `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\lstset{fancyvrb=true}
\fvset{commandchars=\\\{\}}
\begin{document}
\lstinline[language=C++]|(double x){bbbb;}|
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addlegendentry{\lstinline[language=C++]|(double x){bbbb;}|};
\addplot coordinates {( 1, 2 )}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`